# How can I load page content with freeze header on postback?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using asp.net and c#.net.
I'm gonna implement a website that has content navigation like that Microsoft did on this link:
[Microsoft Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/basics#1TC=t1)

In this link you're able to browse page content with freeze header on postback
and also you're able to browse videos from left Navbar without page postback.
The important thing is for each click url is changed.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Thanks and regards

Comment: When you click the links, it looks to me like the whole location is changing, and the entire page is reloading. Are you sure the page is doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: Really? what kind of browser are you using? I tested it with Firefox 16, IE 9, Chrome 22. header section is freeze during postback.

Answer (score 0):

First off, to clarify, postbacks are only required if you're submitting form elements. If you're creating a webforms application, you can easily use controls like `HyperLink` with a `NavigationUrl` to navigate among URLs without needing postbacks.

If what you mean is that you're seeing the page partially updating when following links, that's not what I'm experiencing. The pages appear to completely reload when the links in that page are clicked. In your own site, you can use AJAX and JavaScript to implement a navigation system that doesn't require heavy navigation requests. Look at [Manipulating the browser history (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) for information on exciting new JavaScript features that will let you modify the browser's URL/history without reloading the page. There are several JS libraries that integrate with this feature to give you "AJAX" navigation capabilities.

To simply get the header to not scroll along with the rest of the page, use `position: fixed` in the CSS for the element.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I meant partial updating, I've been looking for this issue about a week, Some developer are using Browser history command for manipulating Url but those commands are not supported for all browsers, I would like to know if there is any other idea.

Comment: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ has been pretty popular. As a fallback for browsers that don't allow history manipulation, it can use the "hash" (URL fragment) for similar effect.

Comment: I've checked this link before. but url is different. are you thinking Microsoft is using history manipulating and Url rewriting?